# Unit testing a started Service which has a few fields injected into it?

Tags: unit-testing, android-service, robolectric, dagger

I am a Dagger newbie.

**TL;DR:**

- If an Android `Service` has any fields injected into it using Dagger, then in order to actually perform the injection, I need to have an instance of that `Service`.
- In Robolectric tests, this corresponds to `MyService service = Robolectric.buildService(MyService.class).get()`. And then, `objectGraph.inject(service);`
- However, rest of the code that actually starts `MyService` still uses `context.startService(context, MyService.class);`.

**Question: What is the idiomatic way in Dagger to address this mismatch?**

---

Let's say I have a `Service` as follows:

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject Parser parser;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data_to_be_parsed");
        parser.parse(data);
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I have an ApiClient class that does this:

```
public class ApiClient{
    public static void parseInBackground(Context context, String data){
        //This service does not have its fields injected
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class).putExtra("data_to_be_parsed", data)); 
    }
}
```

That `parseInBackground` method will be called from an Activity in response to user interaction.

Now, I'm following TDD and hence, I haven't yet written the Application Module for this. Here's the test module:

```
@Module(injects = MyService.class)
public class TestModule {
    @Provides @Singleton Parser provideParser(){
        return new MockParser();
    }
}
```

And finally, the test case:

```
@RunWith(Robolectric.class)
public class ApiTest {
    @Test
    public void parseInBackground_ParsesCorrectly(){
        //This service has its fields injected
        MyService service = Robolectric.buildService(MyService.class).get();
        ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule()).inject(service);

        ApiClient.parseInBackground(Robolectric.application, "<user><name>droid</name></user>");

        //Asserts here
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the test, I retrieve an instance of the service and then inject the `MockParser` into it. However, the `ApiClient` class directly starts the service using an Intent. I don't have a chance to perform the injection.

I am aware that I can have `MyService` perform an injection on itself:

```
public void onCreate(){
    ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule()).inject(this);
}
```

But then, I am hardcoding the `TestModule` here.

Is there an existing idiom in Dagger to set up dependencies for such situations?

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong way to hardcode your modules either in tests or in services. Better approach is to perform creation via your custom `Application` object which in turn will hold singleton `ObjectGraph` object. For example:

```
// in MyService class
@Override public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  MyApp.from(context).inject(this);
}

// in MyApp class
public static MyApp from(Context context) {
  return (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
}

//...

private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

@Override public void onCreate() {
  // Perform Injection
  objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules());
  objectGraph.inject(this);
}

public void inject(Object object) {
  objectGraph.inject(object);
}

protected Object[] getModules() {
  // return concrete modules based on build type or any other conditions.
}
```

Alternatively, you can refactor last method out into separate class and make different implementations for different flavors or build types. Also you may want to set `overrides=true` in your `TestModule`'s annotation.

Comment: I still don't get it. In your example, the second `onCreate()` is within `MyService`, correct? If I need to override `getModules()` then I'll have to create a difference sub-class of `MyService` in my application code versus my test code. AFAIK, you cannot have classes with the same name in `src/main` and `src/test`. So basically, the **class of the Service becomes a dependency for the `ApiClient` class. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: No. Only the first code-block is from `MyService`. Everything else is from `MyApp` - your custom `Application` successor. For tests you can define `MyTestApp` which will extend `MyApp` and override `getModules` method adding dagger-modules only for testing.

Comment: Ah - I see your point now. I'll try your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I realized that I have multiple issues in my question. For one, I am attempting to actually start a service as part of my test - this is not what Robolectric is meant for. I moved that part into a separate instrumentation test. I am now looking into getting the dependency injection part right using Application sub-classes. Will post an answer once I get stuff working.

Comment: @curioustechizen what help do you need exactly? I think everything is mentioned in my answer, isn't it?